# xsens->covariance

Tags: ros, imu, xsens

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
If anyone could help me, I would appreciate.

I have a xsens imu (MTi), I can get the information of the orientation, angular_velocity and accelerations with no problem, however I need the information of the several covariance matrix (it publishes all zeros).
Is there any way to get those?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30709/xsens-%3Ecovariance/) by [PedroS.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2042/pedros./) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2012-03-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You'll have to set up a way to [calculate](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CovarianceMatrix.html) them. I recommend recording the values in arrays and deleting your arrays every once and a while.

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2012-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1